# Ubuntu 12.10 gnome flashback why I get in white toolbar

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I am having big problems with my ubuntu 12.10 and gnome flashback (gnome classic). I always get WHITE toolbar. How to remove it?

[image]

Comment: any idea what has happened?